# How do I change a UIButton state programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

the `.selected` and `.highlighted` properties don't cut it, because for some reason the button looks even more greyed out (darker shade of the non-highlighted image) when highlighted and selected are set to YES.

I need to make my button go off, just as if the user made it go off.
How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'go off', fire an event? Or look a certain way?

Comment: appear like all other not-highlighted buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now think I understand what you mean. I put a image in my UIButton and tried to change the state of the button on touch down.

```
- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    [(UIButton *)sender setHighlighted:FALSE];
    [(UIButton *)sender setSelected:FALSE];
}
```

I noticed that the image does not become darker until you move your finger. If you connect an action to "touch drag inside" and check `.highlighted` you should see that it has turned TRUE again. You could set it back to FALSE:

```
- (IBAction)touchMove:(id)sender 
{ 
    [(UIButton *)sender setSelected:FALSE];
}
```

## However

If you're only looking for a way to stop the image from turning grey when the user presses it, do this:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = FALSE;
```

Setting an image for `UIControlStateHighlighted` would also remove the greying.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "go off" you mean you want to disable the button, you can use:

```
[myButton setEnabled:NO];
```